# Keep Android app running in the background

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working on an app that streams live audio to the device. But, with some devices when the user is browsing the internet the application stops the audio playing. What's the best way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Android Component Called **`Services`** for this kind of background activity. A **[Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)** is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface

Comment: Adding to that, the android system can reclaim application memory at any moment. Services are the only type of activity android would not kill if declared correctly.