# How to run an app in background

Tags: android

I am developing an app using the Smack API. Whenever a message is received for a specific user from a jabber server, a dialogue from the background app should appear to display the message. So a user has to be logged in to display the dialogue. The problem is, it shows the dialogue when the user logs in the first time, but never shows the dialogue when the second message is received. Please Help!

Comment: Please visit my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10778990/996493)

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking at your code. If you want to run a task in background you can use `Service` class in android.

Answer (score 0):

Making a new service in your application and just start the service it will help you to run an app in background.This [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) will help you

Comment: I am using the service.But it is not displaying dialogue.May be user get logged out.Then What is way to keep the user Logged In continuously??

Comment: @Aarti Once you log in a user, its keeps logged in until you log out him or connection to server gets lost. So make sure you are not loosing connection to server when you come out of app.

Comment: I am using service for Log In using Smack API.whenever message from jabber server receives,I have to display the message through dialogue.When app runs first time it receives the message but when it goes in background it never shows the dialogue.I am using service for login of user in background.May be Log in session of that particular user expires.Thats why user never receiving the message.So what's the way to Log In the user upto long??

Comment: You can call a transparent activity from service and in that activity you can call the dialog in oncreate the its works as if you wanted i think so.This is on tricky meathod you can implement.

Comment: @Sreedev I am using the same that is calling the dialogue in On create,But question is still same How to remain connected to server??